# how can i access the courseID variable from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and a java class. I want to access the courseID variable in Generator class from the FragmenrVRList fragment. I tried to declare it as a static variable but it doesn't allowed. How can i do it? Thank you in advance :)

**Generator.java**

```
public class Generator {

public static List<DObjectVrList> getData(){
    int courseID;
    List<DObjectVrList> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<=8;i++){
        DObjectVrList course = new DObjectVrList();
        course.setId(i);
        courseID = course.getId();
        switch (i){
            case 1:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 2:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 3:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course " +i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 4:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 5:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 6:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 7:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
            case 8:
                course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
                course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
                break;
        }
        courses.add(course);
    }
    return courses;
}
```

**FragmentVRList.java**

```
public class FragmentVRList extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
    View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_vr,container,false);
    Generator generator = new Generator();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    AdapterVRList adapter = new AdapterVRList(getActivity(), Generator.getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    switch (Generator.getData())

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have courseID defined inside a static function.  That means the scope of that variable is limited to that function-  it doesn't exist except when that function is being called.

I'm guessing you're a pretty new programmer?  Because the style of this code needs a lot of work.  For one thing, you don't need that switch statement, at all.  Every branch does the same thing.  The entire loop can be rewritten as:

```
for (int i=1; i<=8;i++){
    DObjectVrList course = new DObjectVrList();
    course.setId(i);
    course.setTitleCourse("Course "+i);
    course.setCourseDate("Today at 9 pm");
    courses.add(course);
}
```

In general if you ever find yourself looping and doing a switch on the loop variable, you're almost always wrong.  In fact I see you going for a switch statement later too-  switch statements really aren't used anywhere near as much as you seem to be using them, you need to spend more time thinking about how you're trying to manipulate generic data, rather than making assumptions about individual values.

Then when you want to get the course id, you don't need to access anything in your Generator class.  You just go

```
List<DObjectVrList> courses = Generator.getData();
int courseID = courses.get(index_you_want).getCourseId();
```

If you want to do something to all courses, you go:

```
for(DObjectVrList course : courses) {
    int courseID = course.getCourseID();
    //DO whatever you want with the course id here-  without using a switch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `courseID` is not a member of the `Generator` class; it is a variable local to the `getData()` function.

The course ID seems to be retrieved from `DObjectVrList.getId()`. Since `getData()` returns a list of `DObjectVrList` objects, you can iterate over the list and get the course ID for each `DObjectVrList` in the list using `getId()`.

```
Generator generator = new Generator();
List<DObjectVrList> data = Generator.getData();

for (DObjectVrList course : data) {
    int courseID = course.getId();
}
```